# How to download jetbrains upsource on centOS?

Tags: centos, jetbrains-ide, upsource

Can someone show me how to download jetbrains upsource on CentOS with configurations? Can't find a tutorial online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download Upsource from the [download page](https://jetbrains.com/upsource/download) and install it following the instructions for installing Upsource on Linux.

Make sure you have Java installed, [adjust resource limits](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.0/things-to-configure-before-starting-upsource.html#AdjustResourceLimits(Linux)), and [start Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/3.0/starting-and-stopping-upsource.html).